# All bathroom outlets are dead

Tags: electrical, gfci

We have a house built in 1995; I'm told it was built by a house builder as his own house.

All the bathroom outlets in the house aren't working.

Some are GFCI outlets and some are not.  The presence of non-GFCI outlets suggests to me that there must be another GFCI somewhere although the breaker box doesn't have any other GFCI breakers.

I checked the output side of every circuit breaker in the house and all are working.

All the outside outlets are working too.

At each outlet, I confirmed no voltage from line-to-ground and neutral-to-ground.

I have found that they're all connected together since I used an extension cord and confirmed a connection Line-to-Line and Neutral-to-Neutral between bathrooms at opposite ends of the house.

All this suggests to me that they are all controlled by a single GFCI; perhaps a GFCI breaker.

All the outlets having the GFCI feature are not tripped and also not receiving power.

Unfortunately:

- the house isn't empty
- the plans stored at the city don't include any wiring information
- there is no known property inspection document which may have described a possibly now-hidden breaker box.
- Garage has shelving throughout.
- Basement has a renter.

Any guesses where to look or what special thing I should look for?  I have a background in electronics but so far, I haven't found what I need!

Thank you for any clues you can provide!

Comment: Was the rentable-basement subdivision done by the builder?

Comment: Can you figure out which outlets are attached to the bathroom GFCI's LOAD terminals?

Comment: I predict that you'll find the tripped gfci in the garage, in the least convenient spot.

Comment: Built in 95 the bath should be on 1 circuit it could feed a 2ns bath, a single GFCI outlet may have tripled or failed finding that outlet is probably the source of the outage.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments!  I think the basement rental may have been planned by the builder.  I had found that no bathroom outlet boxes contained any power coming to the outlet.  I checked all the bathrooms in the house.  @Bryce was onto something; I'm going to use one of those wire tracers.  Will let you know what I found!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can rent, or borrow at a tool library, a proper de-energized circuit tracer.  Unfortunately the inexpensive "circuit breaker finders" only work on energized circuits, though you could use one of those in a process of elimination, and to build up a circuit map.

The Ideal Suretrace is the market leader in this category, a basic kit seems to run about $1000.  With that kit you can follow all the wires through walls and even under slabs.

---

You do know you only need one GFCI per room, right?  Only the most upstream outlet should have the GFCI, the rest get stickers indicating they are also protected.

Comment: With the breaker turned off a toner and pickup could be used under 100$ Normally used on data circuits but handy on non energized circuits. Commercial through wall tracers are ~700 for pro models and can be found for less.

Comment: Thanks guys, I had assumed something like that would exist but expected it would have been more expensive.  This is quite doable.  I'll let you know what I found!